# How to get the appID for Facebook and Twitter?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter

I'd like to develop some application that will work with Facebook and Twitter.
From the API introduction, for example, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/ for Facebook, the app ID shall be necessary.

- How do I get the app ID?
- Shall I input it myself in the .plist?
- Or shall I first get it from somewhere of Facebook or Twitter?
- What is the "somewhere"?

Comment: I think i get the information now. For facebook: http://developers.facebook.com/setup/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Twitter: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new

Create your app, and you'll get the ID.

Answer (score 7):

on Twitter, your application ID is the number you got in your application's page URL. 
For example: https://apps.twitter.com/app/xxxxxxx/keys : The xxxxxxx is your app ID number.

Answer (score 0):

To get the App Id

1. first register yourself as a facebook developer, use the following link

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

2.then use following link to generate access token and App ID

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

- happy coding :)